# modified date changes after upload

Tags: box-api

I am integrating with the v2 Box rest api from an iOS app.

When I upload a file I cache it's modified date (as reported by Box in the return JSON)

Sometime later, I request the folder contents and check the modified date on the file (to see if it's changed since I last uploaded.) Depending upon how long I wait, the modified date changes - wtf!!!

If I request the folder contents immediately (msecs) after upload then the modified date is as it was after upload. If I wait 3 or 4 seconds then the date changes (by 1 second typically.)

Anyone from Box know why this might be - and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your particular question, but this caught my eye:

> I ... check the modified date on the file (to see if it's changed since I last uploaded.)

If you're primarily concerned with detecting changes, then you might instead consider using the `etag` or `version` properties of the `file` object. They are designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I guess etag or version could be used as a workaround - but I'm not sure this is something I should need to work around. Modified date has always been the way you could tell that a file has been modified - and it has the advantage of also telling you when. Not tested it - but if the modified date can magically change then perhaps the version field can too?

Comment: Developers have always used 'modified date' to detect changes because it's typically been the best tool that a file systems could offer. But there are several assumptions baked into using it, among them that you'll get at most 1 change per second and that all clocks are perfectly synchronized. `etag` and/or `version` are not subject to those limitations. They're the right tools for this particular job.